# Ruby `respond_to?` returns true when actually false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a fairly simple null object class:

```
class NullObject
  def present?
    false
  end
end

class NullVal < NullObject
  attr_accessor :field

  delegate(
    :allow_edits,
    :box,
    :content,
    :id,
    :locked_for?,
    :number,
    :page_num,
    :page_seq,
    :position_css,
    :position_css_hash,
    :required,
    :required?,
    :size_css,
    :size_css_hash,
    :type,
    to: :field,
  )

  def initialize(field:)
    self.field = field
  end
end
```

and I'm using it in a rails partial cache key:

```
- cache [vals] do
  -# render stuff
```

I'm seeing the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `cache_key' for #<NullVal:0x000000080ceb78>:
  /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb:343:in `block in delegating_block'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:94:in `retrieve_cache_key'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:95:in `block in retrieve_cache_key'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:95:in `retrieve_cache_key'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:95:in `block in retrieve_cache_key'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:95:in `retrieve_cache_key'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache.rb:87:in `expand_cache_key'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/caching/fragments.rb:22:in `fragment_cache_key'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/caching/fragments.rb:43:in `read_fragment'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:183:in `read_fragment_for'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:179:in `fragment_for'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:115:in `cache'
  app/views/docs/_doc.html.haml:13:in `block in _app_views_docs__doc_html_haml___3057171325955977412_79957620'
```

The relevant line of code from `activesupport` is:

```
when key.respond_to?(:cache_key) then key.cache_key
```

If I toss a `puts` in there, it returns `true` for `key.respond_to?(:cache_key)`, and it is, in fact an instance of `NullVal`. If I instantiate a `NullVal` in the console it returns `false` for the same. What is happening here? `method(:respond_to?).source_location` returns `nil` for both...

Comment: It looks like it's delegating method calls to something that doesn't handle it, so you might be inspecting the wrong target. You might need to define `cache_key` on your class. In your example you only show `present?` being defined for reasons that are unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would it delegate `respond_to?` to something other than the object it's being called on? I get the same problem when `present?` is removed, so don't think that's relevant. I'll remove it from the example.

Comment: Also, why the downvote?

Comment: What does the `present?` method have to do with this problem?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I removed it.

Comment: What other code do you have in the NullVal class?

Comment: I added the full definition for the null object class. Didn't seem relevant to me, but I guess it's worth having.

Comment: I think you're chasing a red herring here. Are you absolutely sure that `NullObject.new.respond_to?(:cache_key)` returns `true` and that calling `NullObject.new.cache_key` does not throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured out the problem. I have a `ValDecorator` class that I use to wrap the `NullVal`. When I was printing it to the console it was showing as `#<NullVal:0x0000000a1f3ab0 @field=...>`, but it was in fact the decorator. I'm using `DelegateClass`:

```
class ValDecorator < DelegateClass(Val)
end
```

Since it's using `Val` for `respond_to?` and actually trying to call it on `NullVal`, it throws a surprising error. Will have to think about the implementation of this a little more.